# string replacement in a method with limited variables

Tags: c#

Hi am trying to correct a typo in an exercise that passes in 3 variables.  I am struggling to find a way of doing it.  I can't use 'replace'  because it needs two string variables.  I have tried messing around with substring but haven't figured it.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Week_9_Ex1
{
    class Program
    {    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program fix = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(fix.FixTypo("The Wilking Dead", 5, "a"));                
        }

        public string FixTypo(string needCorrect, int index, string replacement)
        {
            needCorrect.Substring(index, 1);
            return needCorrect;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to reassign the return value from `string.Substring`: `needCorrect=needCorrect.Substring(index, 1);`

Comment: How do I put the needCorrect value into a variable minus the string that I don't need?

Comment: Are you always only replacing a single character?

Comment: return string.Concat(needCorrect.Substring(0, index), replacement, needCorrect.Substring(index+1))

Comment: Yes only replacing a single character because I can't specify length with only one int variable

Answer (score 0):

**First issue:**
Strings are [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You must assign the string to something after you use `Substring` in order to use that value anywhere.

In your question, `FixTypo` gets a substring of `needCorrect` but simply discards it because it's not assigned to anything. Instead you can assign it to itself:

```
needCorrect = needCorrect.Substring(index, 1)
```

...or `return` it directly (which makes an assignment to the return itself)

```
return needCorrect.Substring(index, 1)
```

**Second issue:** To answer the main part of your question, you can easily concatenate multiple substrings of `needCorrect` together using either `String.Concat` or the `+` operator.

For example, this works because you are assigning it directly to the return:

```
public string FixTypo(string needCorrect, int index, string replacement)
{
    return needCorrect.Substring(0, index) + replacement + needCorrect.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

In this example, the `+` operator concatenates three strings together. The first and third strings are a substring of the original. The first substring is from `0` to `index` (the point at which you want to do the replacement (`The W`). The third substring is from `index + 1` until the end of the original string (`lking Dead`).

The middle string is simply the value which you want to use for the replacement (`a`) at `index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring to do the replacement:

```
public static string FixTypo(string needCorrect, int index, string replacement)
{
    // Do some argument checks to avoid exceptions
    if (needCorrect == null ||
        needCorrect.Length < index + 1 || 
        index < 0 || 
        replacement == null) 
    {
        // Note, you may want to throw an ArgumentNullException or 
        // ArgumentOutOfRange exception instead...

        return needCorrect;
    }

    return needCorrect.Substring(0, index) + replacement[0] + 
        needCorrect.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using string.Concat here as opposed to string + string + string

Comment: Better practise in that, at least in older .NET versions (I've not checked recent ones), string + string typically resulted in .NET IL code which essentially creates an array of strings and then joins the two elements.

Comment: Ok ignore that, it no longer seems to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming grovesNL's answer is wrong and you actually wanted to replace the value:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Week_9_Ex1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program fix = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine(fix.FixTypo("The Wilking Dead", 5, "a"));

        }

        public string FixTypo(string needCorrect, int index, string replacement)
        {
            return string.Concat(needCorrect.Substring(0, index), replacement, needCorrect.Substring(index+1));
        }
    }
}
```